# Why doesn't my python package on github show the used by information?

Tags: python, git, github, pip, pypi

Here's my python library : 
https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyYify

Here's another of my libraries : webbot
https://github.com/nateshmbhat/webbot

While `webbot` shows `used by repositories` information on the github page , the `pyYify` library doesn't show ? How to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Used by information does not show up for pyYify, because no other repository mentions pyYify as a requirement.
As you can see by doing a search: https://github.com/search?q=pyYify&type=Code